# Creating a foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

While trying to create two foreign keys at the time of creating a table, I am getting these errors:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'references customer customerid, foreign key productid references product prodc' at line 8

My query:

```
create table orders(
    orderid varchar(10) primary key,
    productid varchar(10)  ,
    customerid varchar(10) ,
    dateoforder  date,
    dateofdelivery date,
    paid decimal(12,2),

    foreign key  customerid references customer (customerid),
    foreign key productid  references product (prodcode)
);
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand But it's a server that has sequel!

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
create table orders(
    orderid varchar(10) primary key,
    productid varchar(10)  ,
    customerid varchar(10) ,
    dateoforder  date,
    dateofdelivery date,
    paid decimal(12,2),

    foreign key  (customerid) references customer (customerid),
    foreign key (productid)  references product (prodcode)
);
```